# can we say ''how late!''?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

can we make an exclamative form by '' How + adjective'' with every adjective

> A) Our class is at 10:00 pm
>
> B) How late!

what can I say instead of (B) for saying that It's too late with that structure?

Answer (score 2):

It works, but it is confusing because of "how"'s frequent use with time phrasing. Some people might think you're asking them a question:

> How late?

As in

> How late in the day is our class?

If you use "How late!" as an exclamation, you may find people repeating the time they just stated to you.

You might try:

> That's late!

as Curtis suggested, or something a bit more vulgar

> God damn, that is a late class!

Answer (score 1):

The expression "How late" can be used, but you can actually use other words besides *late* to convey the sentiment:

> A) Our class is at 10:00 pm
>
> B) How dreadful!

(In this context, one might reasonably assume that the listener would be able to guess that the time is bad because it's late, although there may be other valid reasons as well.

You can also make your language tie into the reasons:

> A) Our class is at 10:00 pm
>
> B) Ugh! I'll never be able to stay up that late!

Answer (score 0):

**How late!** is fine.

**That's late!** also works.